# Error while loading shared libraries: libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 20.04, qt

I'm trying exec the https://biz.mail.ru/myteam/

It works from the `/tmp` dir. But if I try run it from another dir it fails

```sh
$> ~/myteam
/home/user/myteam: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Reinstall of **libqt5*** packages is not effect.

It seems the links between libs aren't configured correctly.

What happens? How can I fix it?

Note that **libQt5QmlModels** is required. I don't understand where to get this for 20.04 and below.

### Additional

```sh
$> ldd ./myteam
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffea9be0000)
    libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 (0x00007fbe29d5d000)
    libQt5DBus.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007fbe29cc1000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007fbe29626000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fbe2903b000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007fbe28e7a000)
    libQt5Multimedia.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Multimedia.so.5 (0x00007fbe28d63000)
    libQt5Concurrent.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so.5 (0x00007fbe28d58000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fbe2880f000)
    libQt5Svg.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so.5 (0x00007fbe287b3000)
    libQt5WebChannel.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebChannel.so.5 (0x00007fbe28790000)
    libQt5WebEngine.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebEngine.so.5 (0x00007fbe28720000)
    libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 (0x00007fbe21a70000)
    libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 (0x00007fbe21a27000)
    libQt5Quick.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0x00007fbe2154e000)
    libQt5QmlModels.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Qml.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007fbe2106f000)
    libQt5Positioning.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Positioning.so.5 (0x00007fbe20fde000)
    libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5 (0x00007fbe20fc7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbe20fbf000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fbe20f9c000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fbe20f55000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fbe20e96000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fbe20e8d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbe20e6a000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbe20e5d000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fbe20e2f000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fbe20e13000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fbe20cd6000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fbe20cd1000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fbe20ca7000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007fbe20c98000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007fbe20c8b000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fbe20c76000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fbe20c71000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fbe20c69000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007fbe20c64000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbe20b13000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbe20921000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbe29f21000)
    libxcb-xinput.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xinput.so.0 (0x00007fbe208fd000)
    libxcb-icccm.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-icccm.so.4 (0x00007fbe208f6000)
    libxcb-image.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-image.so.0 (0x00007fbe206f1000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007fbe206ec000)
    libxcb-keysyms.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-keysyms.so.1 (0x00007fbe206e5000)
    libxcb-randr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0x00007fbe206d2000)
    libxcb-render-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render-util.so.0 (0x00007fbe206cb000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007fbe206bc000)
    libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007fbe206b7000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007fbe206ad000)
    libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007fbe206a1000)
    libxcb-xinerama.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xinerama.so.0 (0x00007fbe2069c000)
    libxcb-xkb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xkb.so.1 (0x00007fbe2067e000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fbe20474000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007fbe20469000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007fbe2044b000)
    libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 (0x00007fbe2043e000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007fbe203fc000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbe202d3000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbe200f1000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbe200d6000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fbe20083000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fbe1fffb000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fbe1ffc3000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fbe1febe000)
    libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007fbe1fe69000)
    libicui18n.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.66 (0x00007fbe1fb68000)
    libicuuc.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.66 (0x00007fbe1f982000)
    libpcre2-16.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-16.so.0 (0x00007fbe1f8ff000)
    libdouble-conversion.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.3 (0x00007fbe1f8e9000)
    libQt5Test.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Test.so.5 (0x00007fbe1f894000)
    libnss3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so (0x00007fbe1f743000)
    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so (0x00007fbe1f710000)
    libnspr4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so (0x00007fbe1f6d0000)
    libevent-2.1.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.1.so.7 (0x00007fbe1f67a000)
    libwebpmux.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebpmux.so.3 (0x00007fbe1f66e000)
    libwebpdemux.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebpdemux.so.2 (0x00007fbe1f668000)
    libwebp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007fbe1f5fc000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007fbe1f577000)
    libre2.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libre2.so.5 (0x00007fbe1f506000)
    libsnappy.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1 (0x00007fbe1f4fb000)
    libXss.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1 (0x00007fbe1f4f6000)
    libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007fbe1f3fb000)
    libavcodec.so.58 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.58 (0x00007fbe1de3c000)
    libavformat.so.58 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.58 (0x00007fbe1dbc4000)
    libavutil.so.56 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so.56 (0x00007fbe1da9b000)
    libvpx.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.6 (0x00007fbe1d863000)
    libopus.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopus.so.0 (0x00007fbe1d804000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fbe1d64a000)
    libxslt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007fbe1d606000)
    libminizip.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libminizip.so.1 (0x00007fbe1d3fb000)
    liblcms2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2 (0x00007fbe1d3a0000)
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007fbe1d327000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fbe1d31f000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fbe1d317000)
    libxcb-util.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-util.so.1 (0x00007fbe1d111000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fbe1d0f7000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fbe1d082000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fbe1cfd3000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007fbe1cf1b000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007fbe1cee7000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fbe1ceba000)
    libpulsecommon-13.99.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-13.99.so (0x00007fbe1ce36000)
    libicudata.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.66 (0x00007fbe1b375000)
    libplc4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so (0x00007fbe1b36e000)
    libplds4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so (0x00007fbe1b369000)
    libswresample.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample.so.3 (0x00007fbe1b347000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fbe1b31c000)
    librsvg-2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librsvg-2.so.2 (0x00007fbe1a9f1000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbe1a991000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007fbe1a86e000)
    libzvbi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzvbi.so.0 (0x00007fbe1a7df000)
    libaom.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaom.so.0 (0x00007fbe1a341000)
    libcodec2.so.0.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcodec2.so.0.9 (0x00007fbe1955b000)
    libgsm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsm.so.1 (0x00007fbe1954c000)
    libmp3lame.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmp3lame.so.0 (0x00007fbe194d4000)
    libopenjp2.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.7 (0x00007fbe1947e000)
    libshine.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libshine.so.3 (0x00007fbe19273000)
    libspeex.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspeex.so.1 (0x00007fbe19255000)
    libtheoraenc.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoraenc.so.1 (0x00007fbe19216000)
    libtheoradec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoradec.so.1 (0x00007fbe191f6000)
    libtwolame.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtwolame.so.0 (0x00007fbe191d0000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007fbe191a2000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007fbe190f7000)
    libwavpack.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwavpack.so.1 (0x00007fbe190cb000)
    libx264.so.155 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.155 (0x00007fbe18e0b000)
    libx265.so.179 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so.179 (0x00007fbe17e9d000)
    libxvidcore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxvidcore.so.4 (0x00007fbe17d8a000)
    libva.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva.so.2 (0x00007fbe17d61000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007fbe17d4e000)
    libgme.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgme.so.0 (0x00007fbe17cff000)
    libopenmpt.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenmpt.so.0 (0x00007fbe17b12000)
    libchromaprint.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libchromaprint.so.1 (0x00007fbe17afc000)
    libbluray.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbluray.so.2 (0x00007fbe17aab000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007fbe178d5000)
    libssh-gcrypt.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh-gcrypt.so.4 (0x00007fbe17849000)
    libva-drm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-drm.so.2 (0x00007fbe17842000)
    libva-x11.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-x11.so.2 (0x00007fbe1783a000)
    libvdpau.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvdpau.so.1 (0x00007fbe17834000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fbe17820000)
    libOpenCL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 (0x00007fbe17616000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fbe175f3000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fbe174d5000)
    libwrap.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007fbe174c9000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007fbe1744b000)
    libasyncns.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007fbe17245000)
    libapparmor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1 (0x00007fbe17230000)
    libsoxr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoxr.so.0 (0x00007fbe171c3000)
    libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007fbe171b7000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbe1718f000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbe16fae000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fbe16f9c000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fbe16f4b000)
    libffi.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007fbe16f3f000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007fbe16e98000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007fbe16e8b000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007fbe16e7e000)
    libmpg123.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libmpg123.so.0 (0x00007fbe16c1c000)
    libvorbisfile.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3 (0x00007fbe16c11000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007fbe16adb000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007fbe16aba000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007fbe16938000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007fbe16920000)
    libnettle.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.7 (0x00007fbe168e6000)
    libhogweed.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.5 (0x00007fbe168af000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fbe1682b000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fbe167de000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fbe167bf000)
    libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007fbe16781000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fbe16765000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007fbe16723000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbe1671d000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007fbe166bb000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fbe16690000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fbe16677000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007fbe1665a000)
    libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007fbe1664f000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fbe16570000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fbe1653f000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fbe16538000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fbe16529000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007fbe164d2000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007fbe16440000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007fbe16436000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fbe1642f000)
```

Comment: libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 is provided by `libqt5webenginewidgets5`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the package which provides the [*libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5) file by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libqt5webenginewidgets5
```

and then retry launching application.

But the libQt5QmlModels is not available for 20.04 LTS, [right](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libQt5QmlModels). You have to ask Mail.ru to make their great app compatible with LTS version. Or upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04 only to get this application to work.

Comment: Unfortunately. I can't find the **libQt5QmlModels** for 20.04

Comment: libQt5QmlModels is not available for 20.04 LTS, [right](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libQt5QmlModels). You have to ask Mail.ru to make their great app compatible with LTS version. Or install Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: You're right. I already sent them an issue. Let's wait.

Comment: OK. It looks like the problem was with the distribution (or in my arms). I just downloaded the new version and it gave me back the additional directories (with the lib). For some reason I was unable to get below level 1 directory before. And you was right about the lib.